# Redirect in different domain XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have to redirect with ajax to different domain. There is bank page. In Php I get adres to redirect when I use function header I got a error in ajax  *XMLHttpRequest cannot load*  so I want to pass this using echo  and i changed dataType:"text", but I can not redirect. Please help me.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/module/payu/paymentMethods",
                header:'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                data: '{ "name":"'+val+'" }',
                contentType: "application/json",
                crossDomain:false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Super' +val);
                },
                dataType:"JsoP",
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown);
                }

           });


echo ("<script>window.location.href='$url'</script>");
                      //  header("Location:".$url,true);
```

Comment: It's `dataType:"jsonp",` not `dataType:"JsoP",`

Answer (score 0):

you should add this header in your php page to allow request from any source , note that it is not good from security measure

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
```

Comment: I always get the same message in console _italic_No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://prestashop.shop' is therefore not allowed access.   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                        header("Location:".$url);

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load ...bank adres...

Comment: you should add header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); in the requested file , but in your case you are using prestashop so should know what is the php file where you should add this header